# twitter bootsrap typeahead jquery ajax callback not working

Tags: jquery, callback, bootstrap-typeahead

ISSUE: twitter bootsrap typeahead jquery ajax callback not working

I am using jQuery v1.8.3, Bootstrap v2.2.1, bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.2.2
Receiving the JSON response but the callback is not getting invoked...

JSON response
`{"ResultSet":{"Query":"face","Result":[{"symbol":"FB"},{}, {}..]}}`

I have seen the different posts related to this issue and tried them. 
But none of them are working for me. Have anyone faced this kind of issues?

```
inputSearch.typeahead({
  source: function (query, processSearchResults) {
    query = inputSearch.val();
    return $.getJSON('ticker_search', { query: query }, function (data) {
      return processSearchResults(data);
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data should be an array like

```
['item 1', 'item 2']
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nbdpD/).

You need to do something like

```
inputSearch.typeahead({
    source: function (query, processSearchResults) {
        query = inputSearch.val();
        return $.getJSON('ticker_search', { query: query }, function (data) {
            if(data && data.ResultSet && $.isArray(data.ResultSet.Result)){
                processSearchResults($.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function(item, index){
                    return item.symbol;
                }));
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nbdpD/1/)

Comment: yeah I agree. But I have the 'processSearchResults(data)' => this callback function forms the array to the source of typeahead functionality. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: `processSearchResults` is the callback method passed from `typeahead` plugin, it is expecting an array, but you are passing an data object.

Comment: You are correct. It was expecting an array. I changed my code as you suggested. It works now. I misunderstood the bootstrap typeahead callback part.Thanks a lot Arun.